# wordpress removes part of the link

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem getting a custom post type link

There is a custom record type — "catalog"
There is a category there, for example, "Screens" with the "screens" slug
In this category, I create a post with the name "Screens" and a slug that was generated automatically — "screens"
Accordingly, the final link should be of the form: some.site/catalog/screens/screens
I get the link in a loop using get_permalink($id)
However, in fact the link turns out like this: some.site/catalog/screens , i.e. the slug of the post (or the slug of the category?) it is not included in final link.

If the "screens" slug is replaced with "screens1" for the category, while leaving the post slug the same — everything is ok
If the post has the "screens" slug replaced with "screens1", while leaving the category slug the same — everything is OK
, i.e., if the category slug and the post do not match, then there are no problems with getting the link

I tried to disable all plugins — no changes, the theme is myself — there are no functions for processing links. htaccess is standard, installed together with WP

If you enter the address some.site/catalog/screens/screens in the address bar of the browser — the page opens correctly

What could be the problem?